# My own rpm doesn't execute %install sequence

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I built for the first time a RPM package. This RPM is a packaged front-end app, and the install only needs to move the app files and do a nginx restart. This is my spec file:

```
Name:           my-portal-app

Version:        2.1

Release:        1%{?dist}

Summary:        Descripcion

License:        No-license

URL:            nourl

Source0:        my-portal-app-2.1.tar.gz

%description
My app install

%prep
%setup -q


%build
#%configure
#make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
#rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
cp -r ./* /var/www/myapp
service nginx restart

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc

%changelog
```

All it's ok when i run rpmbuild -ba, exit 0, and the %install sequence is computed (copy files and restart nginx). Ok, rpmbuild generates the RPM (in rpmbuild/RPMS) and the SRPM in (rpmbuild/SRPMS).

But, if i understand well, when i install my SRPM with rpm -ivh name.rpm **the %install sequence must be executed**, am i right? If i am, sequence is not being executed (not copy files to /var/www/myapp and not restarting nginx). Executing the RPM the same.

The contain of the SRPM is correct, all files are in. And the RPM is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `%install` section is for configure initial RPM build sentences you will need to set up.

To accomplish your goal you must use `%post` section, in that, you can define the execution of your own .sh (for example) or you can set one by one the sentences that you need, for example:

```
sudo service restart nginx
```

For the issue of the empty RPM, it's because `%files` section did not properly filled, the binaries moved to RPM are related with the content of that section (%files)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was wrong... as this [doc](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) says:

> The %install section is not run when the binary RPM package is
>   installed by the end-user, but is only run when creating a package.

Comment: The correct section to accomplish my goal is %post